# ValueError when using ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a Django form that allows users to select options from a dropdown menu, but I am getting a value error:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Form:

```
class DropdownForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
    label = kwargs.pop('label')

    super(DropdownForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['selected'].label = mark_safe(label)
    self.fields['selected'].choices = choices

  selected = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':"form-control text-center"}))
```

View.py:

```
form_rate = DropdownForm(choices=[("HIGH","HIGH")],label="RATE",prefix="Rate")
form_pass_setup = DropdownForm(choices=[("AUTO","AUTO"),("MANUAL","MANUAL")],label="Pass Setup",prefix="pass_setup")
form_dict.update({'form_rate':form_rate,'form_pass_setup':form_pass_setup})

return render(request,'Nominal.html',form_dict)
```

Template:

```
<form action="/InterfaceApp/Nominal_Request/" method="post" class="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="panel-body text-center">
    <div class="row pad_forms">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        {% bootstrap_form form_rate %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        {% bootstrap_form form_pass_setup %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" value="Submit" name="Single">
      {% bootstrap_icon "fire" %} Generate a Single Requests
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this value error?

Comment: Please show the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might occur cause you have not set the required argument `choices` for your `ChoiceField`.

Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield.

Comment: I set it in the form definition with this line `self.fields['selected'].choices = choices`